# Java Microstream - Synthetic classes - PersistenceExceptionTypeNotPersistable

Tags: java, synthetic, microstream

Using Microstream getting the below exception.
Being caused by a class with a reference to a static inner class.
How do I resolve this issue?

The exception states the following, but the documentation doesn't explain how to implement a **PersistenceTypeResolver**

> Details: Synthetic classes ($1 etc.) are not reliably persistence since a simple reordering of source code elements would change the name identity of a class. For a type system that has to rely upon resolving types by their identifying name, this would silently cause a potentially fatal error. If handling synthetic classes (e.g. anonymous inner classes) is absolutely necessary, a custom one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceTypeResolver can be used to remove the exception and assume  complete responsibility for correctly handling synthetic class names.
> at one.microstream.persistence.types.Persistence.derivePersistentTypeName(Persistence.java:1083)

```
    public static final AbstractAccompanyingPassenger DUMMY = new AbstractAccompanyingPassenger(MetaDataAccompanyingType.DUMMY) {
        @Override
        public AbstractAccompanyingPassenger clone() {
            return DUMMY;
        }};
```

```
Caused by: one.microstream.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceExceptionTypeNotPersistable: Type not persistable: "class net.atpco.metadata.summary.accompanied.MetaDataAccompanying$1". Details: Synthetic classes ($1 etc.) are not reliably persistence since a simple reordering of source code elements would change the name identity of a class. For a type system that has to rely upon resolving types by their identifying name, this would silently cause a potentially fatal error. If handling synthetic classes (e.g. anonymous inner classes) is absolutely necessary, a custom one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceTypeResolver can be used to remove the exception and assume  complete responsibility for correctly handling synthetic class names.
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.Persistence.derivePersistentTypeName(Persistence.java:1083)
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceTypeResolver.deriveTypeName(PersistenceTypeResolver.java:17)
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceTypeHandlerCreator$Abstract.deriveTypeName(PersistenceTypeHandlerCreator.java:73)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.types.BinaryTypeHandlerCreator$Default.internalCreateTypeHandlerGeneric(BinaryTypeHandlerCreator.java:238)
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceTypeHandlerCreator$Abstract.createTypeHandlerGeneric(PersistenceTypeHandlerCreator.java:168)
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceTypeHandlerEnsurer$Default.ensureTypeHandler(PersistenceTypeHandlerEnsurer.java:199)
    at one.microstream.persistence.internal.PersistenceTypeHandlerProviderCreating.ensureTypeHandler(PersistenceTypeHandlerProviderCreating.java:170)
    at one.microstream.persistence.internal.PersistenceTypeHandlerProviderCreating.provideTypeHandler(PersistenceTypeHandlerProviderCreating.java:78)
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceTypeHandlerManager$Default.internalEnsureTypeHandler(PersistenceTypeHandlerManager.java:587)
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceTypeHandlerManager$Default.ensureTypeHandler(PersistenceTypeHandlerManager.java:357)
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceTypeHandlerManager$Default.ensureTypeHandler(PersistenceTypeHandlerManager.java:333)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.types.BinaryStorer$Default.registerGuaranteed(BinaryStorer.java:557)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.types.BinaryStorer$Default.registerLazyOptional(BinaryStorer.java:572)
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceObjectManager$Default.ensureObjectId(PersistenceObjectManager.java:182)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.types.BinaryStorer$Default.register(BinaryStorer.java:591)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.types.BinaryStorer$Default.apply(BinaryStorer.java:298)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.types.BinaryValueFunctions$9.storeValueFromMemory(BinaryValueFunctions.java:147)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.types.Binary.storeFixedSize(Binary.java:1149)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.internal.AbstractBinaryHandlerReflective.store(AbstractBinaryHandlerReflective.java:497)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.internal.AbstractBinaryHandlerReflective.store(AbstractBinaryHandlerReflective.java:1)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.types.BinaryStorer$Default.storeItem(BinaryStorer.java:414)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.types.BinaryStorer$Default.storeGraph(BinaryStorer.java:403)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.types.BinaryStorer$Default.store(BinaryStorer.java:421)
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceManager$Default.store(PersistenceManager.java:274)
    at one.microstream.storage.types.StorageConnection.store(StorageConnection.java:306)
    at one.microstream.cache.CacheStore$Default.write(CacheStore.java:112)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem without the need to change the Java Object graph structure and have Synthetic Classes/static references.

1. Implement a *CustomBinaryHandler* for the Object that has the Synthetic Classes/static reference
2. Override the *store* method
3. Override the *create* method
4. Override the *initializeState* method

### Store

If the reference is to a Synthetic Classes/static references create a new instance of the Object and set the reference to a 'marker'.  In my case to a null.  Do not update the current object passed into the *store* method, ensure create a clone and modify the applicable reference.  Then call *super.store()*

### create

Create an empty instance of the Object

### initializeState

1. Retrieve the values for the Object
2. If the value in question has the 'marker' then set it to the Synthetic Classes/static reference
3. Create a clone object and populate with the values
4. XReflect.copyFields from the clone to the real instance

```
public class ExampleTypeHandler extends CustomBinaryHandler<Example> {

    private static Class<Example> handledType() {
        return Example.class; // to get ".class" to work
    }
    
    //the fields to be persisted
    BinaryField<Example> accompanying = Field(Object.class, Example::getAccompanying);
    BinaryField<Example> resulting = Field(Object.class, Example::getResulting);
    
    public ExampleTypeHandler()
    {
        super(handledType());
    }
    
    @Override
    public void store(Binary data, Example dtl, long objectId, PersistenceStoreHandler<Binary> handler) {
        if (dtl.getAccompanying() == MetaDataAccompanying.DUMMY) {
            dtl = Example.of(dtl.getResulting(), null);
        }
        super.store(data, dtl, objectId, handler);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Example create(final Binary data, final PersistenceLoadHandler handler) {
        return Example.of(null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void initializeState(final Binary data, final Example instance, final PersistenceLoadHandler handler) {
        //get the referenced Objects
        Object accompanying = this.accompanying.readReference(data, handler);
        String r = (String)this.resulting.readReference(data, handler);
            
        if (accompanying == null) {
            accompanying = MetaDataAccompanying.DUMMY;
        }

        MetaDataAccompanying a = (MetaDataAccompanying) accompanying;
        Example dtl = Example.of(r, a);
        
        XReflect.copyFields(dtl, instance);
    }       
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the exception states persisting synthetic classes is not supported.
In your case refactoring your classes to get rid of those synthetic classes is the only reliable option.